# How can I map my Matplotlib custom legend to my Networkx graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I've created a working custom legend for my Networkx graph, however I can't get it to be mapped onto my Networkx graph.

Creating the legend:

```
    def _add_legend(self):
        handles = []
        for process, colour in self.colour_map.items():
            handles.append(patches.Patch(color=colour, label=process))

        self.legend = plt.legend(handles=handles)
```

I realised that this was creating a separate graph when I added `plt.show()`.

Plotting the graph:

```
    def _plot(self):
        k = 5/math.sqrt(self.graph.order())
        fig = plt.figure(0)
        pos = nx.spring_layout(self.graph)

        nx.draw(self.graph, arrows=True, with_labels=True, font_size=10, node_color=self.colours, k=k)
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(self.graph, pos=pos, edgelist=self.edges)
        fig.savefig("output.png")
```

How can I map the legend I created using matplotlib to the Networkx graph?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't make it clear in the question body, but I was calling `_add_legend()` *after* `_plot()`. I moved `fig.savefig()` to the end of the legend function and it worked.

Human error. Happy monday, everyone.